# Is it possible to validate key using firebase security rules?

Tags: validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a list year wise inside a node. Is it possible to validate key using `.validate` or something?

like I have a list like this:

```
"list": {
    "year-2015": {
        // data
    },
    "year-2016": {
        //data
    }
    // etc etc
}
```

Can I validate **key** using *regex* `/year-[0-9]{4}/` in security rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Validation rules can be used to validate keys.

You could define a rule like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "list": {
      "$key": {
        ".validate": "$key.matches(/^year-[0-9]{4}$/)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have more data inside that key. How can I write that, then?

Comment: Add some nested rules under `$key` or add additional clauses to the answer's `.validate` rule. There is no example data in your question, so it's not really possible to tell you what you need to do.

Comment: So, I can add ".validate" as well as other nested keys.. right?

Comment: Yes, it's explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Comment: Thanks. I didn't noticed that! :)